# Spark: Yarn Containers to use multiple JMX port on same machine

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, jmx

I am setting JMX configuration in `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` as follows:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false.
```

I wanted to monitor executor and Driver JVMs. But my problem is that more than one container/executor can be started on a single node in my cluster. So I believe there would be port conflict. Is there any solution to handle this scenario or any way i can mention range of ports in JMX configuration , so that executor picks up the free port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `sun.management.jmxremote.port=0` JVM will allocate an ephemeral port.

Now you have to search for the port that was opened by JVM. Run `jps` command to list the processes, there you will see the PID, next step is to look for the port that process is Listening on, use the lsof command!

```
lsof -p <PID> | grep LISTEN
```

Haven't tried it before, let me know if it works!

Comment: Do i need to make com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port = 0 as well?